# instead of FL studio on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: music

I want to install a program similar to FL studio but I don't know a good programs instead.
I want a program to create music with a good instruments.
I have Ubuntu 17.10.

I have tried wine to run FL Studio but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

LMMS is a great alternative to FL Studio.

You can install it by typing: **sudo apt install lmms** into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ardour is an another good alternative to FL Studio.

To install it type **sudo apt install ardour3** into the terminal.